How to split a form into several divs but the first div has another form?
page scheme
here in the picture, the first form is highlighted in black, the second in red. divs are highlighted in orange.
So, I need something like that:
<form1>
    <div>
        text area
        submit
        <form2>
            text area
        </form2>
    </div>
    <div>
        text area
    </div>
</form1>

But that does not work because django just makes the second form a part of the first one

Nesting of form elements is not allowed in HTML.

I understand. That is exactly why I'm asking my question.

Put the two forms after each other, inside the outer div. On each form add an id. To submit, use a button with attribute form="id" with the id matching one of the two forms.
